# "Can't open display" when trying to start X program on a remote machine

Tags: ssh, x11

I have 2 virtual machines, one running CentOS 7 and the other one CentOS 6.5. I'd like to run an application on the CentOS 6.5 VM but display it on the 7 one.

I cannot use `ssh -X` (or `-Y`), I have to use `xeyes -display host:displaynumber`, but I can't manage to make it work for now.

What I'm trying, from the 6.5VM, is: `xeyes -display 192.168.1.20:0`

I get the following:

```
No protocol specified
Error: Can't open display: 192.168.1.20:0
```

However, when I `ssh -X 192.168.1.20` (from the 6.5VM), then `xeyes`, it does work correctly, (and by *correctly* I mean that it successfully connects to the 7VM and the xeyes app is displayed on the 6.5VM) so I don't think it is an issue with the hostname. Doing the other way around (meaning, I ssh from the 7VM to the 6.5VM to launch xeyes) works correctly too.

`echo $DISPLAY` gives `:0` on both machines. I did add `X11Forwarding yes` to /etc/ssh/sshd_config. (and `AllowTcpForwarding yes` too)

Feel free to ask for more information if I forgot something. I'm a bit of a newb so I may have forgotten simple details.

Thanks in advance for any answer!

Comment: First check if the Xorg server on the 7VM is really listening on port 6000 (it's not the default on newer systems!) and if the 6.5VM is able to connect to it. Then try copying the auth from the 7VM to the 6.5VM by running on the 6.5VM; `ssh user@192.168.1.20 xauth extract - :0 | xauth merge -`. Notice that `X11Forwarding` in `sshd_config` only affects ... X11 forwarding (allows you to use `ssh -X` or `-Y`), and when using X11 forwarding `DISPLAY` should NOT be :0.

Comment: And to make it listen on port 6000: Add `-listen tcp`, and make sure that `-nolisten` is not present when starting the X server. Also be aware that X over LAN is inherently unsecure, even with `xauth`.

Comment: `xapp -display host:number` is telling `xapp` to connect to port 6000 + number on `host`; it will not use X11 or any other forwardings you may have set up on the machine it runs on.

Comment: @dirkt I'm sorry if I come across as ignorant, but where am I supposed to add this?

Comment: @mosvy I first wrote a comment but noticed I was wrong, sorry for the notification. Here's what I was saying, but corrected: I forgot to say that, but I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34657/how-to-make-x-org-listen-to-remote-connections-on-port-6000) answer. `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 6000` shows `LISTEN` for this port. However, `telnet 192.168.1.20 6000` is not able to connect. As to copying the auth, your command gives me this: `No matches found, authority file "-" not written; xauth: (argv):1:  unable to read any entries from file "(stdin)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer:

X servers can listen both on a unix domain socket (for local connections) and on a TCP port (6000 + display number). The latter is disabled by default on modern servers, which could be a reason why you can't connect.

So, on the server you want to connect to (the 7 VM), do `ps axu | grep X` or similar, and have a look at the commandline the X server was started with. If there's a `-nolisten` or `-nolisten tcp`, it has to go; and you have to add a `-listen tcp`.

Now there are several ways to start an X server, and I don't know which your system uses. So look at the parent process id (PPID) of the X process, do some more `ps` invocations, and see if you can figure it out. Could be a display manager (e.g. gdm or kdm), or possibly systemd. Whatever started it needs to be configured for those commandline options.

If the server is properly listening on port 6000, the next step is to check firewall rules (iptables).

Comment: I finally got it working. I've done `xhost +` on 7VM and added 6000 port with tcp protocol to the firewall and it worked. I don't know which one of these made it work though. Maybe both? Anyways, thanks for your help !

Comment: Very likely the `xhost +`.